# Jest - mocking a function that uses callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback, mocking, jestjs

I can't get mocking to work. If I provide a mock implementation that's just a method call, it works. But if I replace that with a mock callback implementation, it stops working. What am I doing wrong?

```
// Module.js
export default class Module {
  static navigate(payload, callback) { ... }
}

// setupJest.js
jest.mock('../src/Module', () => ({
  navigate: jest.fn(console.log('test'))                    // works great
  navigate: jest.fn((payload, callback) => { callback() } ) // does NOT work
}));
```

Comment: One workaround is to leave the first statement (`navigate: jest.fn(console.log('test')) `) where it is (setupJest.js), then move the second statement inside the actual test, in this form: `Module.navigate = jest.fn((payload, callback) => callback());`

Answer (score 0):

The only reason `console.log('test')` works is because it executes at the time that you are defining the mock, not when `navigate()` is called.

As long as you're certain that you code is calling `navigate()` (which I'm not sure it is), then you don't really need `jest.fn()`.

```
jest.mock('../src/Module', () => ({                    
  navigate(payload, callback){ 
    console.log('is this really running?')
    callback();
  })
}));
```